# How do dictionaries cope with new meanings of words?

Tags: dictionaries

Scientists are working on every aspect of our lives and find out different information which is sometimes contradictory to the previous information or definitions.

Or sometimes there are some definitions that are not accepted universally.

How dictionaries update these changes?

Comment: **Words do not derive meaning from dictionary entries.** Rather, lexicographers merely document the meanings they find people using. Look at the OED for an historical treatment of words' ever-shifting senses down through the ages.

Comment: In addition, by by reflecting usage, dictionaries typically don't adopt purely technical definitions from science unless they become part of common usage themselves.

Comment: You can read about this [straight from the horse's mouth](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/press-releases/new-words-added-oxforddictionaries-com-august-2014/). Also, it's not uncommon for [news outlets](http://www.cjr.org/language_corner/the_oxford_english_dictionary.php) to write a report when a dictionary is revised, and additions often get mentioned when [pop culture is a driving force](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/2014-The-year-that-was-Selfies-become-Cultural-phenomenon/articleshow/45660370.cms) behind the change.

Comment: Though lexicographers (those who study words and write definitions for them for dictionaries) are literally scientists, researchers of knowledge, most people would be thrown by calling them scientists (that is, calling a lexicographer a scientist sounds weird).

Comment: Is this question about English Language?

Comment: Also, [google does this](https://www.google.com/#q=define:go) (click on "Translations, word origin, and more definitions"). It takes work.

Comment: In my opinion stackexchage site should be like a google for the people who want to search something about English language   if  there would be so much limitation about asking questions the people who have some English knowledge wouldn’t be eager  to use this site and  mostly attracts some individuals with low English  level  like myself   , I have learned a lot from this site and I know there are many people with a good knowledge working with stackexchage but... (the rest of my opinion down this page :next add comment )

Comment: @Saeid - (1) If you have "low English level" you may want to check out [ell.se], which was created for that audience. (2) The Stack Exchange should **not** be a place where people can ask whatever they want; it was designed to be [different](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour), and certain kinds of questions should be [avoided](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq/words_in.htm), the answer is simple: **usage**.

> To decide which words to include in the dictionary and to determine what they mean, Merriam-Webster editors *study the language as it's used*. They carefully monitor which words people use most often and how they use them.

The following is a condensed version.

> The editors scour a cross section of published material in search of new words, new usages of existing words, variant spellings, and inflected forms – in short, anything that might help in deciding if a word belongs in the dictionary. Any word of interest is *marked*.
>
> The marked passages are then input into a computer system and stored both in machine-readable form and on 3" x 5" slips of paper to create *citations*.
>   Merriam-Webster's citation files, which were begun in the 1880s, now contain 15.7 million examples of words used in context and cover all aspects of the English vocabulary. Citations are also available to editors in a searchable text database (linguists call it a corpus) that includes more than 70 million words drawn from a great variety of sources.
>
> Editors review groups of citations. It is the definer's job to determine which existing entries can remain essentially unchanged, which entries need to be revised, which entries can be dropped, and which new entries should be added. In each case, the definer decides on the best course of action by reading through the citations and using the evidence in them to adjust entries or create new ones.
>   Before a new word can be added to the dictionary, it must have enough citations to show that it is widely used. A word may be rejected if all of its citations come from a single source or if they are all from highly specialized publications that reflect the jargon of experts within a single field. Specifically, the word must have enough citations to allow accurate judgments about its establishment, currency, and meaning.
>
> In rare cases, a word jumps onto the scene and is both instantly prevalent and likely to last, as was the case in the 1980s with AIDS.
>
> The size and type of dictionary also affects how many citations a word needs to gain admission. Because an abridged dictionary, such as Merriam-Webster's Collegiate® Dictionary, has fairly limited space, only the most commonly used words can be entered; to get into that type of dictionary, a word must be supported by a significant number of citations. But a large unabridged dictionary, such as Webster's Third New International Dictionary, has room for many more words, so terms with fewer citations can still be included.

Comment: we need more of them  and more of good questions so this site would be as a reference for the people who have some questions, as when somebody types or searches any English question in google,it refers them to stackexchange site on the top of the list, therefore we should not have a rigid mind to attract variety of individuals, that is how I found stackexchange sit.   ..